# If (msg.content == "Ash" || "ash") returns true for any input even if false?

Tags: node.js, if-statement, discord.js

A friend was writing a discord bot using nodejs and ran into an issue where his condition:

```
client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
   if (msg.content == "Ash" || "ash") { 
     msg.reply("sample text");
```

Would always return as true, and the bot would reply to every message sent regardless of its content.

We managed to get around it by removing the ||, but I wasn't able to explain why it didn't work. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Comment: client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
   if (msg.content == "Ash" ||  msg.content == "ash") { 
     msg.reply("sample text");
  }
});

Comment: [Logical Or Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Comment: client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
 if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "ash") { 
  msg.reply("sample text");
 }
})